# Windows (Phone) 8 - image server + app: REST or websockets

Tags: .net, image, rest, windows-8, websocket

I have an idea for an app on windows 8 where I have to use a server (my own) and send several images on daily basis to all the clients. It would also be possible to upload images from  the app to my server.

I have experience in app development on windows 8 and windows phone (7), only C#/XAML. But none of remoting services etc. My question is whether I should use a classic REST API or the newer websockets. I believe the last one has more performance. 
For the record, I'm not going to build a webclient. Maybe, if the app is successful, I'll port it to an Android app. I presume it would be ably to connect to the .NET service regardless of my choice? Are there other important factors that can guide my decision?

So which one should you use?
If you have a link to some good tutorials in .NET regarding REST or websockets (pref. with images, not just hello world), please share :)

Thanks a lot already

Answer (score -1):

The answer is really simple:

```
    When you need a service that provides data use REST, when you need to send some kind of messages or notifications use websockets. Websockets provide a full-duplex communication ( bidirectional ) while the client uses the web api ( so it is unidirectional).

    For example: you have a chat app. Use the service to get the users from the db and use websockets to send messages to users.
```

Check this link for web api
       http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-504
and for websockets:
       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx